# Html in JLabel Java Swing

Tags: html, swing

I tried make JLabel with 2 different font sizes. First is 32pt and second is 16pt, and it should be in the center of Jpanel. Here is my code:

```
label.setText("<html><font size = \"32\"><ul><ul> Shape Stamper!</font>" + 
                "<html><font size = \"16\"><br><b><i>Programmed by:</i></b></font>");



label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
panel.add(programName);


frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using escape strings, try using single quotes inside your double quotes, it makes things much less complicated. For example: 
`label.setText("<html><font size ='32'><ul><ul> Shape Stamper!</font>" + 
                "<html><font size ='16'><br><b><i>Programmed by: Taras Shemberko</i></b></font>");`

To center the string, you could use `<center>` tags or div `<div align='center'>`

Comment: But font still doesn't change size for 32pt and 16pt. I tried to do it with 2 different labels. It was easier set the style and font size, but I cannot set position of label in the center of JPanel.

Comment: try `label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);`